# is it possible to get lua interpreter version information in script?

Tags: lua, version

All I know is how to do it from command line, that is the `-v` switch.

I need something like `phpversion()` or `sys.version` in python. Is that possible ?

Comment: you can get the version within your application, create a function based on it and register that function with lua

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As the duplicate question says, the standard way to get Lua version is:

```
print(_VERSION)
```

Anyway, `_VERSION` will contain a string like `Lua 5.1`, but it's not the same as `lua -v`, which outputs the whole version information including min version number like `Lua 5.1.4`

There is another way: calling `lua -v` directly:

```
io.popen("lua -v")
--Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
```

Note that `io.popen` is not portable, but it should work in both Linux and Windows.

Comment: But for the latter I would need the location of lua executable file. On my system "lua" is not recogized as executable, not added to path.

Comment: I have Centos 6 with Lua 5.1.4 Presintalled. I have downloaded and install the following rpm (http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/21884500/dir/centos_6/com/dba-lua-521-5.2.1-1.1.x86_64.rpm.html) and still shows Lua 5.1.4. I have not clear things about how to enable/install/patch Lua to version 5.2 on my Centos 6. I've read a little about RHEL will not update versions, but i wanna know if is there any way to make it work. Thank you.

Comment: `file = io.popen('lua -v'); print(file:read())` for me on Lua 5.2

Comment: On my console it shows "2013.2.0 r13768", what version is it?